# PHP unable to receive Javascript variable via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> SOLVED: I didn't realize that ajax only sent data in that instance and redirecting created a new instance.

I looked through all the stackoverflow results for help but none of it works.

I am trying to send a variable mmm to php via POST and for some reason the php doesnt retrieve it. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

> Here is the javascript code (in the file checks.js):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'https://www.example.com/panel/app.php',
   data: {mmm: 145},
   success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
   }
});
document.getElementById("adminLoginForm").submit();
```

> Here is the php code in file (app.php):

```
<?php
   $output = (isset($_POST['mmm'])) ? $_POST['mmm'] : 0;
   echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
?>
```

> Google Console Log prints: "Debug Objects: 0"

The file directory is as follows:

Main Folder

- base

  - registration

    - login

      - base

        - js

          - checks.js
- panel

  - app.php

Comment: try use empty($_POST['mmm']) , and debug with a  var_dump the $_POST['mmm'] to see what the php are retrieving

Comment: Are you visiting `app.php` with your browser or were you outputting `data` to the console?

Comment: I want to run that ajax code at a specific function. Shouldn't ajax be executed the moment the function is called?

Comment: Yes I am visiting app.php, ("adminLoginForm").submit() will take the user to the app.php after.

Comment: what php are retrieving in $_POST['mmm']? use a var_dump($_POST['mmm']) to see if php are really retrieving something in the $_POST['mmm'].

Comment: @JohnnyJohn how do you code that?

Comment: you can't redirect to that same `app.php` and expect the ajax data to be there...server will run a new instance

Comment: just check, put a var_dump($_POST['mmm']) or just a var_dump($_POST) to see if php are retrieving your information, before your $output.

Comment: @charlietfl oh ok. how can i pass the variable, while maintaining the submit instance? I dont want to put the variable via URL.

Comment: is form posting to same `app.php`? If so, the variable can go right in the form and can get rid of the ajax

Comment: @charlietfl yes <form id="adminLoginForm" method="post" action="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/panel/app.php">

Comment: so where does `mmm` value come from? All you need is a hidden input, just a matter of how the value gets set depending on it's source

Comment: @charlietfl the mmm value comes from the javascript variable (the variable can only be generated from javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Ajax means you are not doing a form submission by browser action, which refreshes the page. Try get rid of is line and run the code 
`document.getElementById("adminLoginForm").submit();`. You may then get the alert success.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'https://www.example.com/panel/app.php',
   data: {mmm: 145},
   success: function(data){
      alert("success");
      console.log( 'Debug Objects: ' + data )
   }
});
```

And change the PHP script to just echo $output.

Comment: the success method works, but that is not the issue. Even if i comment out that code, then manually go to "https://www.example.com/panel/app.php" the variable is not passed

Comment: *Facepalm*. Ajax means you are still on the same page.  See the example in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting a form to that same php endpoint all you need is a hidden input in the form and can get rid of the ajax

Within a submit event handler you can update the value of the hidden input from whatever source in your script just before the browser posts the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="mmm" id="input_mmm">
```

jQuery submit event listener:

```
$('#adminLoginForm').submit(function(){
    $('#input_mmm').val( new_value);
});
```

From here just submit the form normally using a submit button. That will trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which page contains your Ajax Form submission code. Let us assume you are using the same page, that is **app.php**. Now your page will look like this:

```
<?php
   $output = (isset($_POST['mmm'])) ? $_POST['mmm'] : 0;
   if($output !== 0) {
       echo "SUCCESS: Thanks for submitting value=". $output." Something:".$_POST['something'] ;
       die;
   }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function submitData() {
            var somethingVal = $("#something").val();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'http://localhost/app.php',
               data: {mmm: 145, something: somethingVal},
               success: function(data){
                  $("#message").html(data);
               }
            });

            //document.getElementById("adminLoginForm").submit();
            //Stop form submission
            return false;
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <form method="post" id="adminLoginForm" onsubmit="return submitData()">
            <input type="text" value="Something" name="something" id="something"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Although this is not 100% standard way to achieve things, it just will give you a reference. If you will provide more specific thing you want to achieve, I will help further. I hope it helps!!